# Subquery in Criteria of nHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, subquery, nhibernate-criteria

I need some help with subqueries.
My problem seems easy but I can't figure it out.

I have 3 entities: 
- Companies
- Cars
- Employees

Employee has a list of Companies (but Company doesnt have a list of Employees).
Car has one company.

I need to retrieve all cars from every company some Employee has access to.

Database structure in case it helps.

**Company**

```
id   |     Name
```

**Employee**

```
id   |     Name
```

**CompanyToEmployee**

```
employee_id   |     company_id
```

**Car**

```
id   |  Name   |   company_id
```

As gmiley sugested, I`m adding some mora info.

What I did so far: Not much.

```
ICriteria consult = Session.CreateCriteria<Car>();

DetachedCriteria c = DetachedCriteria.For<Employee>()
   .SetProjection(Projections.Property("Companies"))
   .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Id", employee.Id));

consult.Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("Company.Id", c));
```

But what it returns is all cars within the company with the same Id 'employee' has. And I can see why. But I cant manage to change it to my needs.

Dumb data to clarify:

There are 2 employees: "Bill Gates" e "Steve Jobs.

Bill Gates works for Google and Microsoft.

Steve Jobs works for Google and Apple.

Google has 2 cars: "Car 1" and "Car 2".

Microsoft has 1 car: "Car 3"

Apple has 3 cars: "Car 4", "Car 5" and "Car 6".

What I need:
All cars from all companies Bill Gates works for.

In this case, cars: "Car 1", "Car 2" and "Car 3".

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you could, please include some sample data, an example of your results that you desire, and most importantly, provide some of the code you have tried so far so we know how far along you have made it (it also goes a long way in getting help when people see you have put some effort into it, not saying you haven't, just that it is good to show that you have). Even if you know the code is completely wrong, it helps us understand what you may be thinking.

Comment: Is this homework? Database design is a bit weird. However, it is always possible to have a better class design on top of this. It's not necessary to change either for this query, but it would make life much easier.

Comment: It is a real case scenario exposed in a very simple way. Focusing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to solve my problem in a very simple way:

```
        foreach (var company in user.Companies)
        {
            companies.Add(company.Id);
        }

        consult.Add(Expression.In("Company.Id", companies));
```

Since I already have user companies list, this doesnt give me performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
.SetProjection(Projections.Property("Companies"))
```

You have a whole collection of companies in the projection. I didn't know that this actually runs without syntax error. However, I don't know what it actually does and wouldn't rely on it.

Probably, using alias names would also make things clearer. Try this:

```
var cars = Session.CreateCriteria<Car>("c");

var c = DetachedCriteria.For<Employee>("emp")
   // join
   .CreateCriteria("emp.Company", "comp")
   // select company id
   .SetProjection(Projections.Property("comp.id"))
   // of all companies where the employee is working in.
   .Add(Restrictions.Eq("emp.Id", employee.Id));

carCompanies.Add(Subqueries.PropertyIn("comp.Id", c));
```

Comment: Employee doenst have "Company". It has a list of Companies.